# Secure way of passing parameters in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-props

Route path="name/:para" component={name} />
Is this good approach to pass parameters in reactjs.

Comment: can you be more specific?  for example are you passing parameters from client-> server?

Comment: from client @Nelles for server call like api need specifics id for displaying result and that api is running in didmount so I need to pass these parameters for api, one way is props but I am interested touse this approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is how React has defined to it, 
Incase you want to pass Extra Props , do this

```
<Route
  path='/dashboard'
  render={(props) => <Dashboard {...props} isAuthed={true} />}
/>
```